# MFC how to change font when I move the window?

Tags: c++, fonts, mfc, move

Basically, I am trying to display the output and then update the font of the display when the window is moved. I am trying to use onMove() method to determine if window is moved. However, my problem is somehow, when my program is initialized, it calls the onMove() method instantly. It does not even wait for the window to be moved. Therefore, the font is already changed before the window is moved. What I am trying to do is that, change the font of the display after the window is moved. Honestly, I don't know if there is a way to call onMove() after the window is initialized. In any case, my program will invoke the onMove(). I don't think this is going to be my solution. Does anybody have any other ideas how could I achieve that? Here is a sample execution of What I am trying to do and when I run the program, the test output is already displayed with new font and color. I would like to do that after the window is moved.

```
void CMainFrame::OnMove()
{


 CFrameWnd::OnMove(x, y);

CDC *dc;
dc = GetDC();

CRect rect;


dc->SetTextColor(RGB(255, 128, 0));
CBrush brush;
CFont oFont;

oFont.CreateFont(25, 0, 0, 0, 400, false, false,
    0, ANSI_CHARSET, OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS,
    CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, DEFAULT_QUALITY,
    DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_SWISS, _T("Times New Roman"));

dc->SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT);

dc->SelectObject(oFont);

dc->FillRect(&rect, &brush);

Invalidate();

UpdateWindow();

dc->TextOutW(0, 200, _T("TESTTTT"));

}
```

Comment: What about having a flag that disables the font change, and once initialization is done, clear the flag? That would bypass the initial ‘moving’ the window onto the screen.

Comment: `GetDC` must be followed by `ReleaseDC`, or use `CClientDC dc(this)`. You paint something and then immediately call `Invalidate` which erases previous painting, it doesn't make sense --- `CFrameWnd::OnMove(x, y);` is default processing for `WM_MOVE`. It has nothing to do with your user defined `CMainFrame::OnMove()`.

Comment: To filter out the initial `WM_MOVE` message, set a flag in [CWnd::OnMoving](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4y2xc1b.aspx), and check for it in `OnMove`.